# Is there a way to use a cloth modifier on top of a geo nodes animation?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made this looping flower animation (nodes below) and want to apply a cloth modifier to it, but all while maintaining the geonodes driven animation. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Last time I checked, cloth modifier doesn't work on generated geometry... If you mantain the same number of elements with the same topology, you could reuse them by teleporting them using pinning...

Comment: You could duplicate object, apply GN, surface deform from original, use cloth with pinning following surface deform modifier-- IF your animation doesn't change topology.  But you're not showing what you're animating, so I don't know if you're changing topology.